# create model with nested models with Rails JSON request leads to MassAssignmentSecurity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, backbone.js

Here are my models;

```
class Calendar <ActiveRecord::Base
attr_Accessible :email, :cal_items_attributes
has_many :cal_items
accepts_nested_attributes_for :cal_items
end

class CalItem < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :calendar_id, :name, :url
has_one :calendar
end
```

My website is going to be a backbone application so I do a POST request to localhost:3000/calendars.json as

```
{"calendar":
  {"email":"xxx@gmail.com",
   "cal_items": 
     [{"url":"http://www.google.com"},{"url":"http://www.yahoo.com"}]
  }
}
```

And it returns a error of

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error
in CalendarsController#create 
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: cal_items

I thought the attr_accessible with cal_items_attributes accounted for that!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 2):

You have `attr_accessible` with `cal_items_attributes`, but you used cal_items in the json.

Try:

```
{"calendar":
  {"email":"xxx@gmail.com",
   "cal_items_attributes": 
     [{"url":"http://www.google.com"},{"url":"http://www.yahoo.com"}]
  }
}
```

Comment: Also you do not need `attr_accessible :cal_items_attributes` as `accepts_nested_attributes_for :cal_items` already add it